# Set F1 to close windows

Tags: 14.04, keyboard, shortcut-keys, window

I try to optimize everything. One thing I do frequently is closing windows and closing tabs. Is it possible to set the <kbd>F1</kbd> button to close windows in Ubuntu 14.04? (i.e. same behavior as <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd>) And scroll lock or <kbd>F2</kbd> to close tabs (i.e. same behavior as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>W</kbd>)

Using the `Keyboard` --> `Shortcuts`, the <kbd>F1</kbd> simply opens the help menu for the keyboard application. It cannot set it as shortcut "value". And there's no entry for closing tabs.

The latter may be application-specific. So a keyboard intercepter solution may be the way to go. If possible, I'd like <kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> etc. to keep working.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can keep the <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> shortcut if you define a new custom shortcut. Here are three possible solutions:

## Using `xbindkeys` and `xdotool`

1. Install the packages by opening a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool xbindkeys xbindkeys-config
   ```
2. Run `xbindkeys-config` from the terminal

   [image]
3. Press `New` create a new key binding.
4. Write <kbd>F1</kbd> in the `Key` field to the left or press `Get Key` to grab a key or key combinations. Note that this may create a lot of gibberish such as `Mod2 + F1 | m:0x10 + c:67` but it still works.
5. Enter into the `Action` field to the left:

   ```
    xdotool getwindowfocus key alt+F4
   ```

   .... or whatever other key combination you want to execute.
6. Press `Apply`. It works now.

## Using Keyboard Settings and `xdotool`

1. Install the `xdotool` package, open a terminal and type:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xdotool
   ```
2. Now define a custom keyboard shortcut using the System Settings Menu:

   [image]

   Set the command to `xdotool getwindowfocus key alt+F4`
3. The next step requires to go back to the command line as you can't type <kbd>F1</kbd> to define a new accelerator. So list all the defined custom shorcuts with:

   ```
   $ dconf list /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/
   custom0/
   custom1/
   ```

   The one you've just created should be the last one, here `custom1`.
   Type the following command to assign <kbd>F1</kbd> to close the active window:

   ```
   dconf write /org/gnome/settings-daemon/plugins/media-keys/custom-keybindings/custom1/binding "'F1'"
   ```

   Adjust the `custom<id>` to match yours.

Your new <kbd>F1</kbd> shortcut is ready to use (needless to log out or restart your system) and <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> still works.

## Using Keyboard Settings and `xte`

For keys without special meaning to the Keyboard-application (like <kbd>F2</kbd>), you don't have to go through command line to do the key binding:

1. Install `xte`:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install xautomation
   ```
2. Create your new shortcut using the System Setting menu as explained for <kbd>F1</kbd> just above but with the following command instead:

   ```
   xte 'keydown Control_L' 'keydown w' 'keyup Control_L' 'keyup w'
   ```
3. Assign F2 to the shortcut, it works from the Shortcut window this time.

Comment: I do not have an `/org/`` directory so the ``dconf write`` step returns ``error: 0:expected value``. I did however make the key binding of the ``xdotool`` call work with ``xbindkeys`` (using the ``xbindkeys-config`` interface). That was a bit easier than having to go command line but does require installing ``xbindkeys``. You're welcome to update your answer with that solution or I can do it. I will accept your answer when there's a working solution. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @JonasLindeløv I fixed the command (missing quotes around `"'F1'"`). The `/org/...` is not a path but a schema path used inside the dconf database.

Comment: It works! I've updated the answer with the ``xbindkeys-config`` which is the solution I chose. I hope it's ok.

Comment: @JonasLindeløv Just approved your edit, thanks.

Comment: @SylvainPineau: you're a treasure-trove of knowledge!  Upvoted and Q favourited!